# Spark ML - MulticlassClassificationEvaluator - can we get precision/recall by each class label?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-ml, multiclass-classification

I am doing a multiclass prediction with random forest in Spark ML.

For this MulticlassClassificationEvaluator() in spark ML, is it possible to get precision/recall by each class labels?

Currently, I am only seeing precision/recall combined for all class together.

Comment: Precision/ recall is also removed from lastest version of spark [2.3.0]

Answer (score 1):

Use directly `org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics` and then get metrics available-

```
// copied from spark git
val predictionAndLabels =
      dataset.select(col($(predictionCol)), col($(labelCol)).cast(DoubleType)).rdd.map {
        case Row(prediction: Double, label: Double) => (prediction, label)
      }
    val metrics = new MulticlassMetrics(predictionAndLabels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [class documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/evaluation/MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.html) this doesn't seem to be possible, using the built-in methods.

Although not exactly what you are looking for, you could use `weightedPrecision`and `weightedRecall` in the `metricName` method. This will at least account for class imbalances.